# Why My Chrome is not updated to the latest version?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

In my other pc My chrome version is 120.0.6099.63 but my pain pc is 119.0.6045.200 and it is showing up to date. How can i get the latest version?

I wanted my chrome to be the latest version.
Please Help Me  , it would be very helpful